# muy player start/stop video by javascript

Tags: video, html5-video

I'm embedded my videos with MUX (https://www.mux.com) and the MUX Player.

```
 <mux-player
    stream-type="on-demand"
    playback-id="xxxxx"
    autoplay
  ></mux-player>
```

the video is playing in an overlay. My problem is now, that if the video is playing and the overlay closed, it still plays. How can I control - by javascript/jquery - this video f.e. I want to stop if the overlay is closed. Does anybody have experience with this player und JS.

thanks for any help

Comment: Got a link to your page with the issue on it? Happy to take a look

Comment: @user1272597 If still failing maybe make a normal video tag (to control via JS code by its **id** reference) and just style the buttons to look like Mux player. See [this guide](https://github.com/muxinc/media-chrome) on how to use Mux icons on your own video tag's user interface.

Answer (score 0):

Mux player has prop functions for triggering when it starts playing or when it is paused.

```
onPlay={() => {
    console.log('Started playing')
}}

onPause={() => {
    console.log('Paused')
}}
```

Add these props to the `MuxPlayer` Component and later have a separate variable for storing the state.